# gplt missing from SciPy 0.15.1

Tags: python, import, scipy, missing-data

First I tried with my code in Coderunner

```
from scipy import gplt
ImportError: cannot import name gplt
```

I tried in the terminal

```
>>> import scipy
>>> from scipy import gplt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name gplt
```

Confirmed my scipy version:

```
You are using NumPy (1.8.1) with SciPy (0.15.1)
```

Comment: gplt was removed from scipy about a decade ago, I think.  What tutorial are you following which is suggesting it should be present?

Comment: Good to know! I'm running some code from http://pysces.sourceforge.net/documentation.html